# Excel 2010 Starts with a grey screen, won't open file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Excel won't open my file when I double-click on it.  Excel opens,but just a blank grey screen and no error.

All tip's for internet don't work. I don't have idea how to fix this problem... :( I want open .xls in office 2010, .xlsx work fine but .xls no only gray screen. I use temporary fix, open this files in OpenOffice and convert to .xlsx but it is irritating.

I think it is important information: I using windows 10

Comment: What are the tips from internet you've tried?

Comment: this :

https://computerservices.royalroads.ca/kb/excel-error-starts-grey-screen-wont-open-file

and

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2994633

Comment: What is the location of these files? Were the files downloaded from the Internet? What are your Trust Center settings, specifically for Protected View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has more to do with Excel 2010 than anything else. It started in July after a big security update thru Windows Update. Here is an article to back that up - [Excel refusing to open files? Blame the KB 3115322, 3115262 security updates](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3098898/microsoft-windows/excel-refusing-to-open-files-blame-the-kb-3115322-3115262-security-updates.html).

I started having the issue you described when downloading reports via the Internet. After many frustrating hours, I was able to get Excel to open them with a bit of a work around.

**WARNING: Only do this if you trust the origin of the files.**

1. Open the `Trust Center`.
2. Go to `Protected View`.
3. Deselect the box for `Enable Protected View for files originating
   from the Internet`.

[image]

When you open one of these files you will get a warning message.

[image]

If you click `Yes`, it will open the file. You can then save the file in the proper format for future work.